# SQL / PHP sequential ID numbers

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a certain type of SQL field that acts as a sequential number increasing by 1 each time a row is added.

If not how do we find the highest number of a column with a PHP mySQL query and then increase it by 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want an [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) field.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 1):

You can make a field in a MySQL database increase by 1 for every new row by enabling the `AUTO_INCREMENT` flag. This is a very common (and very good) practice with identifiers within tables.